# error when run SQL statement

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mysql-error-1064

I am developing **Rails** v2.3.2 with **MySQL v5.1** on **Ubuntu** machine.

**MySQL** data directory is `/var/lib/mysql/`

I have a `test.dat` file located on `/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat`

I would like to load data from the `test.dat` file into my database table, so I execute the following SQL statement in one of my **rake task**:

```
namespace :db do
  task :do_something => :environment do

    sql="LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat'
                INTO TABLE myapp.cars;"

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql);
  end
end
```

But I got the following error:

`Mysql2::Error: Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat' (Errcode: 2): LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat`'

What could be the reason??

**P.S.** one thing come to my mind is that `/var/lib/mysql/` can only be accessed by **root user**, but I am not sure if it is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...`.

Comment: I'm thinking the .dat is located at the database server, and the local help?

Comment: YEP!, you are right. the LOCAL helps! Now it is working as expected, thank you. By the way, is the 'LOCAL' has any special meaning, as I have already used the full path of test.dat , Why I still need 'LOCAL'?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention the .dat has root access permission,
change it to 644 might help

Or check the user account that connecting mysql in ruby has the File privileges

```
select File_priv from mysql.user where Host=??? and user=???;
```

Comment: But I have also tried firstly 'sudo su', then run my rake task, it still raise the error(though I changed to root user).